# React useContext throws Invalid hook call error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass a value from a context provider to a consumer using `useContext` and access the value outside of the render function.

My provider looks like so:

```
export const AppContext = React.createContext();

export class App extends React.Component(){
    render(){
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ name: 'John' }} ><Main /></AppContext>   
    }
}
```

My consumer looks like so

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './App';

export class Main extends React.Component(){
    componentDidMount(){
        const value = useContext(AppContext);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>Main Component</div>
        )
    }
}
```

The error is this:

**Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

---

Comment: The error clearly says that hooks can only be called inside function component, and you are trying to use inside class based component. Create function component and it should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use hooks they are designed for function components.  Like so:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './App';

const Main = () => {
  const value = useContext(AppContext);

  return(
    <div>Main Component</div>
  );
}
```

If you want to use it in a class based component then just set it as a static contextType in your class and then you can use it with `this.context` in your component like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './App';

class Main extends React.Component(){

  static contextType = AppContext;

  componentDidMount(){
    const value = this.context;
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>Main Component</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit:
Remove your context from your app component and place it in its own component.  I think you are receiving conflicts in your exporting of your context.

so your app component should look like:

```
import React from "react";
import Context from "./Context";
import Main from "./Main";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Context>
        <Main />
      </Context>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Your main component should be like:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./Context";

class Main extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  render() {
    return <div>{this.context.name}</div>;
  }
}

export default Main;
```

and your context component should be like:

```
import React from "react";

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

class Context extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "John"
  };

  //Now you can place all of your logic here
  //instead of cluttering your app component
  //using this components state as your context value
  //allows you to easily write funcitons to change
  //your context just using the native setState 
  //you can also place functions in your context value
  //to call from anywhere in your app
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Context;
```

Here is a sandbox to show you it working [CodSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2vj4rq9wry)

Comment: This gives an errors in vs code: "Unexpected reserved word 'static'. I'd love to see this work.

Comment: My bad just remove it from the constructor.  I edited the answer and here is a codesandbox for you to see it working https://codesandbox.io/s/oo95rnxko5

Comment: It gives this warning: MainComponent defines an invalid contextType. contextType should point to the Context object returned by React.createContext()

Comment: I think your getting conflicts exporting the context from your app file.  The best way is to create a wrapper component and use that components state as your context value.  Then you can easily change your context on the fly and keep all of your context's logic in its own separate component.  I edited the answer to show you all of the components and gave you a sandbox with a working example.

Comment: @SteveK it works really good however, if I change state in Context.js , it does not reflect in Main.js , Am I am missing something ?

Comment: @SteveK https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-example-forked-ppyvj?file=/src/Context.js

Answer (score 1):

You get the above error because Hooks are meant to be used inside functional components and not class component whereas you try to use it within componentDidMount of Main component which is a class component

You can rewrite your code for Main component using useContext hook like

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './App';

export const Main =() =>{
    const value = useContext(AppContext);
    return (
        <div>Main Component</div>
    )
}
```

or use Context in a different way with class like

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './App';

class Main extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        const value = this.context;
        // use value here. Also if you want to use context elsewhere in class
        // you can use if from this.context
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>Main Component</div>
        )
    }
}

Main.contextType = AppContext;

export { Main };
```

Comment: It gives this error: "MainComponent defines an invalid contextType. contextType should point to the Context object returned by React.createContext()" with the second approach.

Comment: Can you log AppContext in main.js file and see if you are getting the correct value. Also don't forget to export the Main file once contextType is defined as mentioned in the answer

Comment: @Singh, you must create Context in a file different from App.js or else it will result ina cyclic dependency since Main is imported in App and App is imported in Main

Comment: Ohh right! So context should be in the parent (Wrapper.js) and then App.js and then Main.js?

Comment: May not in a wrapper just a different file say context.js and them import it in App and Main from context.js

Comment: So I removed createContext from App.js, added it in Main.js and created another class component Third.js. I tried to consumer the context in Third.js but it still gave me the same error: ThirdComponent defines an invalid contextType. contextType should point to the Context object returned by React.createContext()

Comment: @Singh, There still might be a cyclic dependency somewhere. Can you please create context and export it from 'context.js' file and import it in App and Main both. Working like this should solve the problem for you

Answer (score 0):

Hooks only work with stateless components. You are trying to use it in class component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the content for `Main.js` file. Uncomment the commented part if you want to use class-based component instead of the functional one.

```js
import React from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./App";

/** UNCOMMENT TO USE REACT CLASS COMPONENT */
// class Main extends React.Component() {
//   render() {
//     return (
//       <AppContext.Consumer>
//         {value => <div>It's Main component. Context value is ${value.name}</div>}
//       </AppContext.Consumer>
//     );
//   }
// }

const Main = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(AppContext);

  return <div>It's Main component. Context value is ${value.name}</div>;
};

export default Main;
```

Here is the content for `App.js` file. Uncomment the commented part if you want to use class-based component instead of the functional one.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Main from "./Main";

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

/** UNCOMMENT TO USE REACT CLASS COMPONENT */
// export class App extends React.Component() {
//   render() {
//     return (
//       <AppContext.Provider value={{ name: "John" }}>
//         <Main />
//       </AppContext.Provider>
//     );
//   }
// }

const App = () => (
  <AppContext.Provider value={{ name: "John" }}>
    <Main />
  </AppContext.Provider>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

React Hooks were implemented directly for the functional components in order to give them the possibility to become stateful. Class-based components were stateful all the time, so you have to use their own `state` API.

Working demo is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/xr41xy24lq).